# some product thumbnails doesn't show up

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, thumbnails

Hi a have a store with woocomerce and noo theme.
Im having trouble with some product thumbnails.

Some considerations:

The image are loaded from my wordpress gallery (4 for each product)
and loaded on woocomerce product color variations

In this product , the images show up ok

https://soygorrion.com.ar/tienda/mochilas/fresa-2/

Here is when I have the problem

https://soygorrion.com.ar/tienda/mochilas/nogal/

No thumbails show up

I install the thumbnails regenerator and doesnt fix the problem

I compare both products page are fill in the same way (color variations, sizes,etc)

Want to recover the product thumbails

Comparing the code from the two products

I see this code is missing from the product that has no thumbnails

Please see this fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/webg6rua/

```
<div class="noo-woo-all-images-wrap noo-woo-all-images-wrap--thumbnails-below noo-woo-reset" data-showing="1896" data-parentid="1896" data-default="[{&quot;large&quot;:[&quot;https:\/\/soygorrion.com.ar\/wp-content\/uploads\/2018\/07\/fresa4-562x700.jpg&quot;,562,700,true],&quot;single&quot;:[&quot;https:\/\/soygorrion.com.ar\/wp-content\/uploads\/2018\/07\/fresa4-500x623.jpg&quot;,500,623,true],&quot;thumb&quot;:[&quot;https:\/\/soygorrion.com.ar\/wp-content\/uploads\/2018\/07\/fresa4-100x100.jpg&quot;,100,100,true],&quot;alt&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;title&quot;:&quot;fresa4&quot;},{&quot;large&quot;:[&quot;https:\/\/soygorrion.com.ar\/wp-content\/uploads\/2018\/07\/fresa1-562x700.jpg&quot;,562,700,true],&quot;single&quot;:[&quot;https:\/\/soygorrion.com.ar\/wp-content\/uploads\/2018\/07\/fresa1-500x623.jpg&quot;,500,623,true],&quot;thumb&quot;:[&quot;https:\/\/soygorrion.com.ar\/wp-content\/uploads\/2018\/07\/fresa1-100x100.jpg&quot;,100,100,true],&quot;alt&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;title&quot;:&quot;fresa1&quot;},{&quot;large&quot;:[&quot;https:\/\/soygorrion.com.ar\/wp-content\/uploads\/2018\/07\/fresa2-562x700.jpg&quot;,562,700,true],&quot;single&quot;:[&quot;https:\/\/soygorrion.com.ar\/wp-content\/uploads\/2018\/07\/fresa2-500x623.jpg&quot;,500,623,true],&quot;thumb&quot;:[&quot;https:\/\/soygorrion.com.ar\/wp-content\/uploads\/2018\/07\/fresa2-100x100.jpg&quot;,100,100,true],&quot;alt&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;title&quot;:&quot;fresa2&quot;},{&quot;large&quot;:[&quot;https:\/\/soygorrion.com.ar\/wp-content\/uploads\/2018\/07\/fresa3-562x700.jpg&quot;,562,700,true],&quot;single&quot;:[&quot;https:\/\/soygorrion.com.ar\/wp-content\/uploads\/2018\/07\/fresa3-500x623.jpg&quot;,500,623,true],&quot;thumb&quot;:[&quot;https:\/\/soygorrion.com.ar\/wp-content\/uploads\/2018\/07\/fresa3-100x100.jpg&quot;,100,100,true],&quot;alt&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;title&quot;:&quot;fresa3&quot;}]" data-slide-count="4">


                <div class="noo-woo-images-wrap">

                    <div class="bx-wrapper" style="max-width: 100%;"><div class="bx-viewport" aria-live="polite" style="width: 100%; overflow: hidden; position: relative; height: 307px;"><div class="noo-woo-images noo-woo-images--click_anywhere" style="width: 4215%; position: relative; transition-duration: 0s; transform: translate3d(-246px, 0px, 0px);"><div class="noo-woo-images__slide  bx-clone" data-index="3" style="float: left; list-style: none; position: relative; width: 246px;" aria-hidden="true">


                                <img class="noo-woo-images__image" src="https://soygorrion.com.ar/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/fresa3-500x623.jpg" data-noo-woo-src="https://soygorrion.com.ar/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/fresa3-500x623.jpg" data-large-image="https://soygorrion.com.ar/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/fresa3-562x700.jpg" data-large-image-width="562" data-large-image-height="700" title="fresa3" alt="" width="500" height="623" style="">

                            </div>


                            <div class="noo-woo-images__slide noo-woo-images__slide--active" data-index="0" style="float: left; list-style: none; position: relative; width: 246px;" aria-hidden="false">


                                <img class="noo-woo-images__image" src="https://soygorrion.com.ar/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/fresa4-500x623.jpg" data-large-image="https://soygorrion.com.ar/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/fresa4-562x700.jpg" data-large-image-width="562" data-large-image-height="700" title="fresa4" alt="" width="500" height="623">

                            </div>


                            <div class="noo-woo-images__slide " data-index="1" style="float: left; list-style: none; position: relative; width: 246px;" aria-hidden="true">


                                <img class="noo-woo-images__image" src="https://soygorrion.com.ar/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/fresa1-500x623.jpg" data-noo-woo-src="https://soygorrion.com.ar/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/fresa1-500x623.jpg" data-large-image="https://soygorrion.com.ar/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/fresa1-562x700.jpg" data-large-image-width="562" data-large-image-height="700" title="fresa1" alt="" width="500" height="623" style="">

                            </div>


                            <div class="noo-woo-images__slide " data-index="2" style="float: left; list-style: none; position: relative; width: 246px;" aria-hidden="true">


                                <img class="noo-woo-images__image" src="https://soygorrion.com.ar/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/fresa2-500x623.jpg" data-noo-woo-src="https://soygorrion.com.ar/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/fresa2-500x623.jpg" data-large-image="https://soygorrion.com.ar/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/fresa2-562x700.jpg" data-large-image-width="562" data-large-image-height="700" title="fresa2" alt="" width="500" height="623" style="">

                            </div>


                            <div class="noo-woo-images__slide " data-index="3" style="float: left; list-style: none; position: relative; width: 246px;" aria-hidden="true">


                                <img class="noo-woo-images__image" src="https://soygorrion.com.ar/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/fresa3-500x623.jpg" data-noo-woo-src="https://soygorrion.com.ar/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/fresa3-500x623.jpg" data-large-image="https://soygorrion.com.ar/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/fresa3-562x700.jpg" data-large-image-width="562" data-large-image-height="700" title="fresa3" alt="" width="500" height="623" style="">

                            </div>


                    <div class="noo-woo-images__slide noo-woo-images__slide--active bx-clone" data-index="0" style="float: left; list-style: none; position: relative; width: 246px;" aria-hidden="true">


                                <img class="noo-woo-images__image" src="https://soygorrion.com.ar/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/fresa4-500x623.jpg" data-large-image="https://soygorrion.com.ar/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/fresa4-562x700.jpg" data-large-image-width="562" data-large-image-height="700" title="fresa4" alt="" width="500" height="623">

                            </div></div></div><div class="bx-controls bx-has-controls-direction"><div class="bx-controls-direction"><a class="bx-prev" href=""><i class="icon ion-ios-arrow-back"></i></a><a class="bx-next" href=""><i class="icon ion-ios-arrow-forward"></i></a></div></div></div>

                    <div class="noo-woo-loading-overlay"><i class="fa fa-circle-o-notch fa-spin fa-fw"></i></div>

                </div>





                <div class="noo-woo-thumbnails-wrap number-4 noo-woo-thumbnails-wrap--sliding noo-woo-thumbnails-wrap--vertical" style="opacity: 1; height: auto;">

                    <div class="bx-wrapper" style="max-width: 800px; margin: 0px auto;"><div class="bx-viewport" aria-live="polite" style="width: 100%; overflow: hidden; position: relative; height: 360px;"><div class="noo-woo-thumbnails" style="width: auto; position: relative; transition-duration: 0.2s; transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);">




                                <div class="noo-woo-thumbnails__slide noo-woo-thumbnails__slide--active" data-index="0" style="float: none; list-style: none; position: relative; width: 70px; margin-bottom: 20px;" aria-hidden="false">

                                    <img class="noo-woo-thumbnails__image" src="https://soygorrion.com.ar/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/fresa4-100x100.jpg" title="fresa4" alt="" width="100" height="100">

                                </div>



                                <div class="noo-woo-thumbnails__slide " data-index="1" style="float: none; list-style: none; position: relative; width: 70px; margin-bottom: 20px;" aria-hidden="false">

                                    <img class="noo-woo-thumbnails__image" src="https://soygorrion.com.ar/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/fresa1-100x100.jpg" title="fresa1" alt="" width="100" height="100">

                                </div>



                                <div class="noo-woo-thumbnails__slide " data-index="2" style="float: none; list-style: none; position: relative; width: 70px; margin-bottom: 20px;" aria-hidden="false">

                                    <img class="noo-woo-thumbnails__image" src="https://soygorrion.com.ar/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/fresa2-100x100.jpg" title="fresa2" alt="" width="100" height="100">

                                </div>



                                <div class="noo-woo-thumbnails__slide " data-index="3" style="float: none; list-style: none; position: relative; width: 70px; margin-bottom: 20px;" aria-hidden="false">

                                    <img class="noo-woo-thumbnails__image" src="https://soygorrion.com.ar/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/fresa3-100x100.jpg" title="fresa3" alt="" width="100" height="100">

                                </div>


                            <div style="float: none; list-style: none; position: relative; width: 70px; margin-bottom: 20px;" aria-hidden="false"></div>

                    </div></div></div>

                    <a href="javascript: void(0);" class="noo-woo-thumbnails__control noo-woo-thumbnails__control--up" data-direction="prev" style="display: none;"><i class="fa fa-chevron-up-open-mini"></i></a>
                    <a href="javascript: void(0);" class="noo-woo-thumbnails__control noo-woo-thumbnails__control--down" data-direction="next" style="display: none;"><i class="fa fa-chevron-down-open-mini"></i></a>

                </div>

                </div>
```

Comment: seems there are no thumbnails for this page: https://soygorrion.com.ar/tienda/mochilas/nogal/ 

Can I get the access of the site where I can check the setup of the thumbnail

Answer (score 0):

Check if those photos are correctly displayed at your WP Media Library, try to download them to your pc, then remove them from product, and upload again.

Watch for errors during upload, and if they display correctly on gallery in admin panel.

Comment: Thank you! I tryed everything you wrote also upload other images that are not related to the product, but the thumbnails not appear. Comparing the code of the two pages.